# SQLAlchemy does not find new entries

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy

i made a python flask web application that lists database entries.
There is a form to add a new entry. It uses `db.session.add()` and then `db.session.commit()`
After adding a new entry, it doesn't appear in the web applications list, while all other entries are listed.
When I look for the entry in the MySQL Database via `SELECT ...`, I can see that the entry exists.
After I restart MySQL via `sudo service mysql restart`, the new entry appears in the web application.

Do You have a Idea why this happens?
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

`db.session.add()` only creates the db request in memory.

You need to call `db.session.commit()` to persist the changes.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I am using the `db.session.commit()` command, so i edited the question. The addition to the database works fine, but the database needs to be restarted to see the new entry in the web application.

Comment: you don't need to restart the database, you just need to make a GET endpoint listing all the table entries and call it from the frontend after you created the new item.

Comment: ok, sounds good. How can I make this kind of endpoint in python?

Comment: this is where flask helps you ! https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/